# While loops vs Joins for the CRUD Operations in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a doubt in using while loops in the SQL SP will affect the performance of database. Generally, I would prefer the use joins to do the CRUD Operations in SQL. But i would like to know which one will give better performance.

Comment: Avoid looping in SQL whenever possible.

Comment: Looping = RBAR (**row-by-agonizing-row**) processing.... avoid it!

Comment: Thank for the answers. I already know but i want to confirm that one

Answer (score 3):

Set based logic will always be faster when written properly.